# How would I translate "Learn things, help people"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

Like the title says, how would I translate "learn things, help people"?  Someone had suggested to me "nova cognosce hominesque iuva".  I know "res" means more "matter, affair" so I guess "nova", in the sense of "new things" would be better?

Also, if I didn't want to use the "-que", what would be the best word order to get the appropriate meaning across without punctuation? thanks.

It's for a motto. I guess I'm pretty open as far as style goes. Something simple, yet gramatically correct.

Answer (score 4):

I think *nova cognosce hominesque iuva* works pretty well. Of course, there are only about a zillion different ways to say this. Starting with the simplest, I'd say:

*Disce et iuva*. Learn and help. There you have it.

Moving on, maybe something like:

*Quae iuvant disce*. Learn what helps.

*Disce ut homines iuves*. Learn that you may help people.

*Disce ad homines iuvandos*. Same as above.

There are many more possible ways to say something like this. I could go on, but I'd like to hear some others' ideas.

Comment: I think "disce ut iuves" would work pretty well

Comment: @Laravel & Figulus: I didn't get the sense that op's statement was a purpose clause, though it does make for a better motto.

Comment: Well its statement was "Do A, do B", so I think the implied meaning was "Do A so that you can do B" but I could be wrong